# How do I test that a sequence of data satisfies the Central limit theorem?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I have some data stored as a list from some computations. I want to calculate the "distance" the sequence is away from satisfying the central limit theorem.

I would like to know, what should I use as the "distance"? And how do I calculate it?

This is based on a conjecture that the data satisfies the central limit theorem and I'm looking for computational evidence for it.

Comment: Your question is quite incomplete.  What is your ultimate goal?  Why do you care about the central limit theorem in particular, and on using asymptotic methods in finite sample sizes in general?

Comment: I updated the question, i'm basically looking for a way of getting computational evidence.

Comment: That in no way describes the motivation for doing this.  The CLT is seldom helpful in real life and mainly protects type I error, having little to do with type II error (or power) or precision of estimates.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know the sufficient sample size for CLT to work? But how would you definite it works? It'll only approach to normal for some large data size. Also, are your samples independent? Can't you just plot the sample distribution and do a test against the normal?

Answer (score 1):

The Central Limit Theorem is about the limiting distribution of the sample average as the sample size gets large. That limit is the normal distribution, under certain conditions (mean and variance exist, the observations are independent.). CLT-like results exist for dependent data when the dependence is sufficiently weak.

I assume you want to know if your sample is large enough for the normal distribution to be a good estimate for the distribution of the sample average. To this end, I would create a bootstrap distribution of the sample average and see if it looks normal. I'm not sure exactly how you would test for normality ... maybe a Kuhlback-Leibler.

Alternatively, you can just wing it. The CLT works pretty quickly if the original distribution is symmetric. If your sample size is at least 30, and your data are symmetric and don't have hideous outliers, you can safely use the normal distribution for the distribution of the sample average.

Comment: That is not so true if $\sigma$ is unknown.  Highly asymmetric distributions not only destroy the meaning of $\sigma$, they make the CLT unhelpful.

Comment: That's why I said that the distribution should be symmetric for convergence to be rapid.

Comment: I should have added that heavy tails can hurt severely if $\sigma$ is unknown, even if the distribution is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Negative Entropy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negentropy

which is zero if the distribution is Gaussian, non-negative otherwise, and can be approximated with higher order moments. Otherwise you could simply use the fourth order cumulant (kurtosis) and determine if the distribution is super-Gaussian or sub-Gaussian by comparing the estimated value with that of a Gaussian.